# 3D transformation error, memory error.

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, 3d, transformation

```
triangle* tri = new triangle((GraphicsContext::RED), x1, y1, z1,
                    x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3);
            std::cout << "PASSED triangle instantiation" << std::endl
                    << std::endl;
            add(tri);
            std::cout << "PASSED add" << std::endl << std::endl;
            tri->draw(gc, vc);
            //delete (&tri);
            std::cout << "PASSED draw method" << std::endl << std::endl;
```

So when looking at this, it is inside an open_file method. I open a file, read 3 lines, each like contains 3 doubles. an x, y, and z.
so I need all 9 for a triangle to form(3D transformation)
it passed every method except draw on the first time around. once it goes into draw, i get 
" *** Error in `./lines': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x088d7c50 ***
Aborted "
Which i have never seen before. Can someone please help.

```
    void ShapeContainer::draw(GraphicsContext* gcontext, viewContext* vContext) {
    for (auto sDraw : image) {
        sDraw->draw(gcontext, vContext);

    }
}
```

I know this is alot of code and I apologize for that, but I believe it is all necessary code in order to kind of see what I am donig and notice where the issue would be.

```
  void triangle::draw(GraphicsContext* gcontext, viewContext* vContext) {

    matrix temp(4, 1);
    matrix temp2(4, 1);
    matrix temp3(4, 1);

    temp[0][0] = origin[0][0];
    temp[1][0] = origin[1][0];
    temp[2][0] = 1;
    temp2[0][0] = origin[0][1];
    temp2[1][0] = origin[1][1];
    temp2[2][0] = 1;
    temp3[0][0] = origin[0][2];
    temp3[1][0] = origin[1][2];
    temp3[2][0] = 1;

    temp = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp);
    temp2 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp2);
    temp3 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp3);

    //set color to color input from constructor.
    gcontext->setColor(color);
    //x1,y1,x2,y2
    gcontext->drawLine(temp[0][0], temp[1][0], temp2[0][0], temp2[1][0]);
    //x2,y2,x3,y3
    gcontext->drawLine(temp2[0][0], temp2[1][0], temp3[0][0], temp3[1][0]);
    //x3,y3,x1,y1
    gcontext->drawLine(temp3[0][0], temp3[1][0], temp[0][0], temp[1][0]);

    std::cout << "just drew a triangle" << std::endl;
}
```

This is the model to device 3D method.

```
    matrix viewContext::model_to_device_3D(const matrix& param) {
    matrix hold_values(param); //copy
    //TODO [0][2] OR [2][0]
    hold_values[0][2] = 1;

    hold_values = (M3D * hold_values);

    //TODO not sure if matrix divison works
    //may have to do 1/hold_values[3][0] then multiply that with hold_values
    double temp = 1 / hold_values[3][0];
    hold_values = hold_values * temp;

    return hold_values;
}
```

M3D is what i wanted my composite matrix to be for the 3D transformation

Comment: Most likely, somewhere there is a pointer that has gone past the valid range of places to point at and wrote garbage into something important.

Comment: Off topic: if you have defied your matrix object the way I think you've defined it, you may find you get a nifty performance improvement by replacing the 2D array with a 1D array.

Comment: On topic: Have you stepped through the draw routine with a debugger or hit your program with valgrind? Valgrind is often the bomb for finding blow-ups like this.

Comment: @user4581301 I actually have no idea how to use Valgrind, i should definitely check it out